# Error with a query - Doctrine2/Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to execute a simple query, but I can't understand where is my mistake. Please help!

This is in the repository class:

```
public function searchFriends ($param)
    {
         return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT f FROM EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend f WHERE f.name='.$param)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

And this is how I call it from the controller's action:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
 $result = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
              ->searchFriends($search->getWords());
```

When it's in this way, I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 54 near 'Maria': Error: 'Maria' is not defined.
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
```

I tried to put the searched value in quotes in this way:

```
public function searchFriends ($param)
    {
         return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT f FROM EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend f WHERE f.name=" '.$param ' " ')
            ->getResult();
    }
```

but then I get

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 59: Error: Expected end of string, got ' " '
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
```

Could you please tell me how to write the query correctly? Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

I also tried this:

```
public function searchFriends ($param)
{
     $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->where('f.name = :name')
        ->setParameter('name', $param)
        ->getQuery();

     return $q->getResult();
}
```

with this:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
 $result = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
              ->searchFriends($search->getWords());
```

and it's workiiing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I wouldn't use this way of passing parameters to a query (check [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html)), your mistake is in the way you built the string that lacks a dot. It should be like this:

```
public function searchFriends ($param)
    {
         return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT f FROM EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend f WHERE f.name="'.$param.'"')
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: When the dot is there, the mistake is [Syntax Error] line 0, col 59: Error: Expected end of string, got ' ' :( I will try the other way, too.

Comment: When I copied the code you gave the error is still [Syntax Error] line 0, col 54: Error: Expected Literal, got ' " '

Comment: Can you show your current code? You have a syntax error, it should be easy for you to see what it is

Comment: My current code is the code which @adosaiguas posted. I also edited my answer, in the other way it's working :) Thank you @adosaiguas!

Comment: I still think you haven't copied the code corretly, the second error you posted can't be generated by the code I posted. And well, if I my answer solved your issue, shouldn't you accept it? :)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that I copy it correctly, the mistake is still there. My question was about how to solve the problem with the errors and from where it comes, because it seems strange. But you are right, your suggestion to use the QueryBuilder solved my problem, so I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the literal expression:

```
public function searchFriends($param)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('f.name', $qb->expr()->literal($param)));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```